How to use identity in React ASP.NET Core project?
I have created a new React & ASP.NET Core project and added identity by scaffolding. Then, I published this project on GitHub publicly. The project repository can be found at
https://github.com/hmahdavi921/ReactApp1.git
I need to implement identity on the server side to incorporate SMS and email functionalities. The current Identity API implementation does not allow for customization.
How can I do it?

Inside the github repo , I found it generate the related razor page, what you want for this? You want to modify the identity page to an identity web api ? Inside of using the identity razor page?

@BrandoZhang  I want to load these razor pages when the user needs to log in.

I think you could directly access the web api's identity page, by using the  https://webapiurlIdentity/Account/Login to login the user.
